# Hololens2 and Unity: Using QR Code to place Objects/Markers in relation to it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object, hololens, mrtk

I'm currently working on a unityproject with Hololens 2 MRTK and the quite new QR package for MRTK, which I loaded via Nuget. The following idea I want to implement:
Imagine a physical component with two connectors on it and one of them is supposed to be surrounded by a circle (similar to the introduction video of Hololens 2). Now another user should be able to load the scene and see the circle on the connector, even if the part has been positioned differently in space.
I thought about adding a QR code to the part and setting the circle in relation to the QR code so that the user can only scan the code once before and then arrange the objects correctly.
Do you have an idea how to do this in Unity?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the following... :)

"HoloLens 2 can detect QR codes in the environment around the headset, establishing a coordinate system at each code's real-world location."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/qr-code-tracking

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, I'll take a closer look. Another question then at this point: Could I mock a QR Code in Unity so that I don't always have to deploy the application?

Comment: We ended up wrapping the QRCodes as there is no sensible way to instantiate that class from your own code. I also think they are not using the main camera of the hololens for tracking QR Codes(the light indicating the camera is off), so you cannot simulate this in the editor.